# URL redirect Windows azure web sites

Tags: azure, web-config

I am trying to redirect my url in windows azure web-sites. I am trying to modify the web config file in order to do this, without luck:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
  <location path="https://www.test-domain.org.uk/">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="https://www.test-domain.org.uk/portal/" 

httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>

</configuration>
```

I want to redirect all requests to https://www.test-domain.org.uk/portal/ to https://www.test-domain.org.uk/

Comment: This is not azure (web sites) specific and probably handled through one of the countless IIS redirect questions.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/21684930/web-config-file-how-to-redirect-from-url-to-url here is a specific question for this. thanks.

Comment: That was not what I meant. Please use the search function which leads to great answers [like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3082146/468244).